# Multiplicative persistence using recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

I was trying to make a function that calculates the [multiplicative persistence](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultiplicativePersistence.html) on my own.
It works when I pass in a number that has a multiplicative persistence **value of 2 or less**.

But when passing in a number whose multiplicative persistence is **more than 2**, it is returning an **incorrect value**.

Here is the function I wrote:

```
function persistence(num) {
  let res = 10
  let count=0
  const helper = (number)=>{
    res=1
    const digits = number.toString().split('')
    for(let digit of digits){
      res = res* Number(digit)
    }
    count++
    console.log(res,count)
    return
  }
  if(num<10) return 0
  if(res>=10){
    if(count===0) helper(num)
    helper(res)
  }
  return count
}
```

Comment: Your code currently calls helper just once, `if (res >= 10)`, but you want to call helper repeatedly `while (res >= 10)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the digit multiplication by using a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce); then it is simply a matter of returning either `0` if `num < 10` or `1 + persistence(prod)` if `num > 10`:

```js
const persistence = (num) => {
  if (num < 10) return 0
  const prod = num.toString().split('').reduce((acc, d) => acc * d, 1)
  return 1 + persistence(prod)
}

console.log(persistence(5))
console.log(persistence(437))
console.log(persistence(1379))
```